# Word for a friend you have never met?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expression-choice

Can anyone provide "emotional" word/phrase for a "friend" you have never met, but it feels like you really know him? I won't mind even if it was in a language other than English. :)

*Update*: Would love it if the word/phrase was related to literature.

Comment: What about "imaginary friend"? Always there but you never meet in person. They are often depicted as a shadow or one's own shadow.

Comment: No need to delete the question if it may be useful to others.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same notion, but such a person might often be referred to as one’s ***kindred spirit***. A kindred spirit can be someone you know, too, though.

Comment: [Fictiophilia](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fictiophilia) means an attraction to fictional characters, but it's not a common word.

Comment: Related, but different: [Is there a word yet, for old friends who've just met?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/320527/115786)  Related possible duplicate: [Is there a word for someone who you've not physically met but know well?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194533/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-youve-not-physically-met-but-know-well)

Answer (score 4):

**Pen pal**

> a person with whom one becomes friendly by exchanging letters,
>   especially someone in a foreign country whom one has never met.

Answer (score 1):

[Kris Rosvold asserts](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-meaning-of-this-quote-by-Jim-Henson-There%E2%80%99s-not-a-word-yet-for-old-friends-who%E2%80%99ve-just-met/answer/Kris-Rosvold-1) that

> there is such a word, used in the Pooh stories and in Richard Bach's stories: **Unmetfriend.**