# Is there a word yet, for old friends who've just met?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the original Muppet Movie ([lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/back-there-lyrics-muppets.html), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryEjm3k6uY0)), Jim Henson asserted there *is* not, but that was 1979.

Now it's a few decades later, and the English language has evolved, including a lot around changing speed and depth of new relationships.  It seems possible that there might be a word that describes a first meeting of two people that is accompanied by a resonating familiarity, [déjà vu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu), and sense of overlap in perspectives and values, leading to a feeling of a strong relationship despite the absence of actual length.

Also in the past few decades, we've gained the EL&U Stack Exchange, where such a question can be asked.  So, give it your best shot!

The target word could be a noun describing a person (with grammatical usage similar to other relational terms like *friend, enemy, acquaintance, companion,* etc.) or the feeling (with usage similar to *déjà vu* but focused specifically on a person and indicating a feeling of strong connection but not necessarily a confusion over having actually met the person or interacted extensively with them before).  Upvotes would also be given for words that describe the experience/encounter/scene (with grammatical usage similar to *[meet cute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_cute)*).

[Kaukokaipuu](http://www.cnn.com/2016/06/24/health/words-for-emotions/), "a feeling of homesickness for a place you've never visited," is something that may be reduced/resolved by the event of meeting this person, although with kaukokaipuu it seems like you know in advance what it is that you're missing.  The [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316265403) with that word may also have an answer to this question.

Comment: What about "affinity" ? (a natural harmony or attraction to other persons)

Comment: The phrase "new best friend" gets some usage. You could say the friend's "just click".

Answer (score 2):

It is tempting to co-opt *fast friends* for this purpose ([as was done in an online blog](http://friendship.about.com/od/Types_of_Friendships/g/Fast-Friends.htm)), but it would be a gross deviation from the [traditional idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fast+friends).  *Fast* in this case refers to [*steadfast*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/what-does-fast-friends-mean).

A phrase that may apply may be ***[newfound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newfound) friend***, although it does not exactly express how quickly the relationship formed. An *old acquaintance* may become a *newfound friend*.

As a twist, you could try combining the two:

> This is Robert, my ***new fast friend***.

Answer (score 1):

In a search, the closest I could find is "Instant Rapport," presumably described in a [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Instant_Rapport.html?id=9J9tPwAACAAJ) of that title by Michael Brooks published a decade after the song quote adapted for this question's title.

Comment: It would be better to include this with your question.

Comment: It is an answer, that can be voted/discussed on its own merit, even if it carefully leaves the door open for it not being the only/best answer.  See also http://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: It wasn't my down vote. This answer seems to be research that led to an unsatisfactory result, which is why I suggested making it a part of your question.

Comment: Had someone else asked this question, I would not have downplayed the answer as much; I did so here so as to signal openness (beyond the weak signal that the answer isn't Accepted, which is not even a signal within the first couple days after posting when accepting one's own answers isn't possible) and encourage other answerers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything so I made my own. How about "friendship at first sight?"  It's not elegant but I think most folks would understand it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Soulmates" is close but that might be too intimate.
I've heard the term, "Twin brothers from different mothers" before but it leaves sisters out.
Agape is "fraternal love" but implies a long term, developed bond.
There's something about "resonance" that I like but isn't new friend specific
No standalone word comes up immediately, sorry !

Answer (score -1):

Common ground:

> opinions or interests shared by each of two or more parties.
>
> "artists from different cultural backgrounds found common ground"

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/common_ground)